# How do I make match stop on first occurance?

Tags: ruby, xml, regex, match, bbcode

I need to digest some bbcode with a Ruby regular expression.

I have to delimit the elements with the `match` command and use a regexp `/pattern/m` to get rid of newlines.

For example, my bbcode in a string is:

```
s="[b]Title[/b] \n Article text \n [b]references[/b]"
```

Then I use `match` to delimit the parts of the text, especially the Title and the References parts which are enclosed between `[b]` and `[/b]`:

```
t=s.match(/\[b\](.*)\[\/b\]/m)
```

I use `(..)` syntax to catch a string in the regexp and I use `\` to escape the special `[` and `]` characters. `/m` is to get rid of newlines in the string.

Then `t[1]` contains:

```
"Title[/b] \n Artucle text \n [b]references"
```

instead of `"Title"`. because the match doesn't stop at the first occurance of `[/b]`. And `t[2]` is nil instead of "References" for the same reason.

How can I delimit the text parts enclosed between the usual bbcode tags?

Answer (score 9):

Use non-greedy operator `?` like this:

```
t=s.match(/[b](.*?)[/b]/m)
```

Comment: "Greedy" means that regex tries to consume as much input as possible. "Non-gready" means the opposite. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you will not encounter opening square brackets between your bbcode tags, you can use a character class that excludes them:

```
t=s.match(/\[b\]([^\[]*)\[\/b\]/)
```

But if your `[b]` tags can contain other tags, you need to use a recursive pattern:

```
t=s.match(/(?x)
    # definitions
    (?<tag> \[ (?<name> \w++ ) [^\]]* \]
            (?> [^\[]+ | \g<tag> )*
            \[\/\g<name>\]
    ){0}

    # main pattern
    \[b\] (?<content> (?> [^\[]+ | \g<tag> )* ) \[\/b\]
          /)
```

And if you have to deal with self closing tags:

```
t=s.match(/(?x)
    # definitions
    (?<self> \[ (?:img|hr)\b [^\]]* \] ){0}
    (?<tag> \[ (?<name> \w++ ) [^\]]* \]
            (?> [^\[]+ | \g<self> | \g<tag> )*
            \[\/\g<name>\]
    ){0}

    # main pattern
    \[b\] (?<content> (?> [^\[]+ | \g<self> | \g<tag> )* ) \[\/b\]
          /)
```

Note: the `{0}` allows to define named subpatterns that can be used later without matching anything.